# Prolog Problem. I need help to solve this issue

Tags: prolog

```
student(stud04, 'Database', 59).
student(stud04, 'Math 3', 67).
student(stud04, 'Data Structures', 79).

prerequisite('Database', 'Data Warehouses').
prerequisite('Math 2', 'Math 3').
prerequisite('Math 3', 'Math 4').
```

Comment: You have not asked a question, nor identified what your "issue" is.

Comment: Without a problem statement, it is . . . rather difficult to help you.